# javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E

Tags: servlets

While publishing EAR file on WAS7.0 server , I'm getting below exception.

I have placed all the required jars at WEB-INF/lib, rebuild app many times but unable to resolve it...

```java
com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor createServletWrapper 
Servlet action is currently unavailable: SRVE0203E: Servlet [action]: Action Servlet 
was found, but is missing another required class.
SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled 
with classes which cannot be located by the server.

SRVE0187E: Check your class path to ensure that all classes required by the servlet 
are present.SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using 
only the classes in the application's runtime class path

com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor createServletWrapper Error 
occured while preparing the servlet for initialization. 
javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created 
by servlet
```

What should I do to resolve this? Getting 404 when I hit application on server.
My web.xml file is validated and has no errors.

Please tell me probable solution to resolve this exception.

Comment: What part of "This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server" don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of compatibility issue.

I was getting this error when I included jersey jars. Some of the jars need minimum jdk 1.7

I reduced the version of my jars in pom.xml.

It is working fine for me.

Comment: its working fine in local development environment for jdk1.6. but in WAS 8.5 server ,reeving the same exception